# Get ads analytics data by Member company on Creative Level

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I am using the Linkedin Ads Analytics API, and I hitting the following API
`{{baseUrl}}/adAnalyticsV2?dateRange.start.month=11&dateRange.start.year=2022&dateRange.end.day=15&dateRange.end.month=12&dateRange.end.year=2022&q=analytics&timeGranularity=ALL&pivot=MEMBER_REGION_V2&projection=(*,elements*(*,pivotValue~(*)))&accounts=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:######&dateRange.start.day=16#`

Now It gives me data on REGION level, which means the pivots are region like `urn:li:geo:90009649`, the problem is the data is not on a creative level or campaign level. I want to get this demographic data on a creative level, and not on the whole account level.

Things I have already tried.

1. using the statistics finder -- It does not have demographic pivots
2. using the pivot[0], pivot[1] for the analytics finder, -- It does not work, only one pivot.
3. trying to give campaign Id list-- the data still does not contain it on ad levels.

Things I have already tried.

```
using the statistics finder -- It does not have demographic pivots
using the pivot[0], pivot[1] for the analytics finder, -- It does not work, only one pivot.
trying to give campaign Id list-- the data still does not contain it on ad levels.
```